# JetAppointment schedule error in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Crocoblock & Jetappointment in my woocommerce website selling service offer, I have different types of services with duration, but I want to block my schedule if I book a service.

Actually, If someone buy "A" service tomorrow at 9, someone else can't book "A" service in the same slot, but he can book "B"service on this appointment, even if i check this option :

[image: availability]
all my services have duration set :
[image: schedule]

Can someone explain me how to solve this bug ?

Thanks and sorry for my poor english, I'm a french Baguette